# Matching Google Play Services device installation with Xamarin.GooglePlayServices libraries

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, google-play-services, compatibility

I am currently upgrading my Xamarin application. I have updated my Xamarin.GooglePlayService nuget packages to v42.1021.1, previously the version was 29.0.0.2.

When I start my app I check whether play services are available. I get an error which says SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED, which I expected.

But my question is how do the packages I use to build my app relate to the version of the google play services which needs to be installed on the phone.

For example, on various phones I have version 9.4.52 and 10.0.84 of Google Play Services installed, both of which are compatible with the 29.0.0.2 versions of the Xamarin.GooglePlayServices packages.

How do I know which versions are compatible with my 42.1021.1 versions of my  Xamarin.GooglePlayServices packages

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nuget version vs. the Play Services version are listed in the README.md on Xamarin GooglePlayServicesComponents repo:

```
| NuGet / Component Version |  Google m2repository Version | Google Play Services Version |
|---------------------------|------------------------------|------------------------------|
| 25.0                      | 19 (GPS SDK 25)              | 7.5.0                        |
| 26.0                      | 21 (GPS SDK 26)              | 7.8.0                        |
| 27.0                      | 22 (GPS SDK 27)              | 8.1.0                        |
| 29.0                      | 24 (GPS SDK 29)              | 8.4.0                        |
|                           | 25                           | 8.4.0 (no binary changes)    |
|                           | 26                           | 9.0.0                        |
| 30.0.1.alpha4             | 27 (GPS SDK 30)              | 9.0.1                        |
| 30.0.2-alpha1             | 28                           | 9.0.2                        |
|                           | 29                           | 9.2.0                        |
|                           | 30                           | (never published)            |
|                           | 31                           | 9.2.1                        |
| 32.4.0-beta2              | 32                           | 9.4.0                        |
| 32.961.0                  | 32                           | 9.6.1                        |
| 42.1001.0                 | 42                           | 10.0.1                       |
```

Re: https://github.com/xamarin/GooglePlayServicesComponents#versioning